# JavaScript order JSON by SUM

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, json

So what we have is a JSON string that looks like below:

```
[{"id":"1499","tradingname":"Golden Shutter Photography","listed":"2012-01-26 19:26:24","pictureurl":"","business_id":"1499","storeid":"1","phone":"6143737477","street":"122 Avebery Drive","suburb":"Berwick ","state":"1","postcode":"3806","discription":"","long":"","lat":"","offer":"500|50","tstamp":"2012-01-26 19:26:24","offers":"500|50"}]
```

What we need is a JavaScript way to order/shuffle the results so that they take the offers and order it in away that it shows the most difference last and the less first.

For example, say the offers in the JSON are the following

```
100|10

100|20

100|9
```

it would put it in the order of

```
100|20

100|10

100|9
```

Now the issue will be that some offers have more then 1 offer so they are like follows

```
100|20,100|9,100|10
```

in this case we want to move the 100|9 to the end too look like this

```
100|20,100|10,100|9
```

Comment: @rdlowrey I have tried to order it at the MySQL point and use jquery .sort

Comment: why sort the orders in javascript? use multisort in php to order the array before using json_encode.

Answer (score 0):

This should give you an idea. But it would be more effective to sort the array in php using multisort before calling json_encode.

```
 var arr = [
      {"id":"1498","tradingname":"Golden Shutter Photography1","listed":"2012-01-26 19:26:24","pictureurl":"","business_id":"1499","storeid":"1","phone":"6143737477","street":"122 Avebery Drive","suburb":"Berwick ","state":"1","postcode":"3806","discription":"","long":"","lat":"","offer":"200|60","tstamp":"2012-01-26 19:26:24","offers":"200|40"},
      {"id":"1499","tradingname":"Golden Shutter Photography2","listed":"2012-01-26 19:26:24","pictureurl":"","business_id":"1499","storeid":"1","phone":"6143737477","street":"122 Avebery Drive","suburb":"Berwick ","state":"1","postcode":"3806","discription":"","long":"","lat":"","offer":"400|50","tstamp":"2012-01-26 19:26:24","offers":"200|50"},
      {"id":"1500","tradingname":"Golden Shutter Photography3","listed":"2012-01-26 19:26:24","pictureurl":"","business_id":"1499","storeid":"1","phone":"6143737477","street":"122 Avebery Drive","suburb":"Berwick ","state":"1","postcode":"3806","discription":"","long":"","lat":"","offer":"200|50","tstamp":"2012-01-26 19:26:24","offers":"400|50"}
    ];


    function sortbyoffer(a,b) {
      var aa = a.offer.split("|");
      var bb = b.offer.split("|");
      if(aa[0] == bb[0]) {
        return aa[1] - bb[1];
      } else {
        return aa[0] - bb[0]; 
      }
    }

    arr.sort(sortbyoffer);

    for(var n=0;n<arr.length;n++){
      document.write(arr[n].id + ' ' + arr[n].tradingname +  ' ' + arr[n].offer + '<br>');
    }
```

output would be:

```
1500 Golden Shutter Photography3 200|50
1498 Golden Shutter Photography1 200|60
1499 Golden Shutter Photography2 400|50
```